# set definitions with empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A little question about set definitions based on other sets. $X^- = \{X \setminus \{x\} \mid x \in X\}$ is an example of such a set. What happens if one looks for $\emptyset^-$? I have this feeling there's something to say for $\emptyset^- = \emptyset$ and $ \emptyset^- = \{\emptyset\}$.

In the first case one could argue that you can't find any singletons $\in \emptyset$ and thus the collection should be empty.

In the second case it's possible to use the argument that $\emptyset \setminus \emptyset = \emptyset$ and thus the empty set should be in the collection.

Could anyone tell me what the right way to argue about this is, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the former that's true. $\varnothing^-=\varnothing$. Your argument is exactly correct.

$A\in\varnothing^-$ if and only if there is some $x\in\varnothing$ such that $A=\varnothing\setminus\{x\}$. But there is no such $x$, so there are no such $A$.

Comment: just for clarity: $\{1\}^- = \{\emptyset\}$, right? Or is it $\emptyset$ too?

Comment: Right again. $\{x\}^-=\{\varnothing\}$, regardless to what $x$ is.